# Check if user is logged-in inside sessions_start hook handler

Tags: sessions, hook

I am aware that in sessions_start handler function, the session object is not yet set.

Since I can't use the session object, are there alternative ways to check if you are logged in  in this function handler?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no session, then there is no logged in user. All of the user login code runs after the sessions_start hook.

Comment: I looked at [sessions_end](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/168569/#882060). It has the same problem. I used these session hooks because I wanted to set a session variable(language). Are there any hooks that can do this job?

Comment: Yes, sessions_end is your ticket in. Look at libraries session.php. The hook provides $this (i.e. the session class itself) and the userdata is in $this->userdata